# Multiclass multilabel confusion matrix where predictions and labels are multi-hot vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I need to calculate the confusion matrix for labels and predictions that are represented as multi-hot vectors. Seems that sklearn does not support such scenario.

Here's an example of what I have. Suppose there are three classes, `'a', 'b',` and `'c'`; the targets/labels are:

```
l1 = [1, 0 ,1, 0, 0]; of class a
l2 = [1, 0 ,1, 0, 1]; of class b
l3 = [1, 0 ,0, 0, 0]; of class a
l4 = [0, 0 ,0, 0, 0]; of class c
```

So, we have label matrix:

```
L = np.array([ [1, 0 ,1, 0, 0], 
[1, 0 ,1, 0, 1], 
[1, 0 ,0, 0, 0],  
[0, 0 ,0, 0, 0]] )
```

predictions are:

```
p1 = [1, 0 ,1, 0, 0]; of class a
p2 = [1, 0 ,1, 0, 0]; of class b
p3 = [1, 1 ,0, 0, 0]; of class a
p4 = [0, 1 ,0, 0, 0]; of class c
```

and the prediction matrix as:

```
P = np.array([ [1, 0 ,1, 0, 0], 
[1, 0 ,1, 0, 0], 
[1, 1 ,0, 0, 0],  
[0, 1 ,0, 0, 0]] )
```

I expect the output to be a `3x3` confusion matrix, something that roughly looks like the following:

```
   A  B  C
A  2  0  0  
B  0  0  1
C  0  1  0
```

I am using `sklearn`  `accuracy_score` to estimate the classification accuracy. However, although `accuracy_score` is working for the accuracy on such labels, the `sklearn` confusion matrix does not support the above scenario. Are there any alternatives to `sklearn`?

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886370/multi-class-multi-label-confusion-matrix-with-sklearn) seems to give three confusion matrices, which is not the case I am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain how you are assigning the class labels `a, b, c`? How are `l1` and `l3` both `class a`?

Comment: Well, in a dataset one can have, say, 120,000 samples distributed into three labels. If the dataset is balanced, then, 40,000 belong for each class, i.e., `a` has 40,000, and so do `b` and `c`.

Comment: Better said, `l_n`is the lable of the `n_th`  sample

Comment: So just to clarify, you have multi-hot labels of size 5 which are then distributed into 3 classes based on the combinations or some other condition?

Comment: Correct!  In my problem, I have hundreds of thousands spread over 6 classes, each has sub-categories and that is why I need multi-label classification. The above is just to simplify the problem.

Comment: If you know the mapping of label vectors to your classes, then why not use the same on your prediction vectors as well and then generate `confusion_matrix` using these mappings?

Comment: The mapping is used as a ground truth, both in accuracy and confusion scores. 
I don't want to spend time to write this confusion matrix function if it is available as open-source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189146/discussion-between-panktijk-and-innuendo).

Comment: OK. I have 5 minutes now as I am preparing to leave.

Answer (score 0):

I think accuracy is not the right metric to be used in this kind of situation. You could rather use `roc_auc_score` from the `sklearn.metrics.ranking`.

Comment: Thanks! My concern is the confusion matrix, and BTW, the `accuracy_score`  does support multi-hot. I've edited the text to be clearer of why I am connecting the accuracy to the confusion matrix.